# Best approach to ocurrences of ids on a table and all elements in another table

Tags: sql, postgresql, redash

Well, the query I need is simple, and maybe is in another question, but there is a performance thing in what I need, so:

I have a table of users with 10.000 rows, the table contains id, email and more data.

In another table called **orders** I have way more rows, maybe 150.000 rows.

In this **orders** I have the **id** of the user that made the order, and also a **status** of the order. The **status** could be a number from 0 to 9 (or null).

My final requirement is to have every user with the **id, email, *some other column* , and the number of orders with status 3 or 7.** it does not care of its 3 or 7, I just need the amount

But I need to do this query in a low-impact way (or a performant way).

What is the best approach?

I need to run this in a redash with postgres 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a `join` and `group by`:

```
select u.*, count(*)
from users u join
     orders o
     on o.user_id = u.user_id
where o.status in (3, 7)
group by u.user_id;
```

Postgres is usually pretty good about optimizing these queries -- and the above assumes that `users(user_id)` is the primary key -- so this should work pretty well.

Comment: Could it be even faster if `o.status in (3, 7)` is moved inside the `join` clause, either as is, or expanded to `(o.status == 3 or o.status == 7)`? Is there a way to predict which is faster without `explain analyze`?

Comment: It will be the same, performance-wise. Postgres is smart enough to treat all these as equivalent

Comment: and what about in cases where I want to do it as excluding, I mean when i want those who are not  status 3?   WHERE o.status IN (<<every that is not 3>>)